# How to compile a package in Java from command prompt in Windows 7 system

Tags: java

I am learning Java from ‘Java2: The Complete Reference by Schield”. I am using a Windows 7 system with command prompt (JDK) to compile and execute Java programs. I am trying to compile a program having a package as seen in the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
package MyPack;
class Balance
{
    String name;
    double bal;
    Balance(String n, double b)
    {
        name = n;
        bal = b;
    }
    void show()
    {
        if(bal<0)
        {
            System.out.print("--> ");
            System.out.println(name + ": $" + bal);
        }   
    }
}
class Account
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Balance current[] = new Balance[3];
        current[0] = new Balance("K. J. Fielding", 123.23);
        current[1] = new Balance("Will Tell", 157.02);
        current[2] = new Balance("Tom Jackson", -12.33);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) current[i].show();
    }
}
```

When I execute either

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac" Account.java” (from within the MyPack folder
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac" MyPack/Account.java (outside the MyPack folder)
```

I receive the following error:

```
“ Account.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected package MyPack;”
```

or

```
“MyPack\Account.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected package MyPack;”
```

Please let me know how I can compile and then execute such a program?

Comment: there is only one way to compile a java program using `javac` . Can you elaborate you error ? Is that compilation error or runtime error ?

Comment: your problem is that your import statement is before your package declaration, your code is invalid

Comment: Yes this is one reason for your errors

Comment: you used this command  **javac -d . filename.java** (-d) is Destination to place generated .class file and (. Dot) is Current working Directory(CWD). i hope it used full @Monty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html

> The package statement (for example, package graphics;) **must be the
>   first line in the source file**. There can be only one package
>   statement in each source file, and it applies to all types in the
>   file.